# Get error when rebuild index in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Got Error when i rebuild the index in sql server 2008.
Lock request time out period exceeded. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1222)

Comment: The error says it all: SQL Server was unable to get the locks necessary to rebuild the index. So it couldn't rebuild the index. You need to make sure that no one else, no other process, no other client, is using that database before you start rebuilding the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably did not commit the transaction properly,

To fix this error you should run the following queries:

1. run ->   DBCC opentran()
2. (Find SPID like 55 or 66)
3. run ->   KILL      (like Kill 55)